# Showing that $P_3$ is a subspace of $C[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, proof-verification, vector-spaces, topological-vector-spaces

$P_3=\{ a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3: a_i\in \mathbb{R} \}$, and $C[0,1]$ is the set of all functions continuous on $[0,1]$. I need to show that $P_3\subset C[0,1]$ by exposing its basis and dimension. We know that in order to show that a subset is a subspace of a vector space we need to show closure under addition and scalar multiplication, as well as that the zero-element is in the subset. But here it appears different. I'm not completely sure if my understanding is correct, so I would appreciate if my solution is reviewed.

Solution:

Let $H$ be a basis for $C[0,1]$, then $H$ is infinite. Also, $C[0,1]$ includes all polynomial functions since they are continuous on $\mathbb{R}$, thus the infinite dimensional basis $J:=\{1, x, x^2,...\}$ is a subset of $H$. The basis for $P_3$ is $K:=\{1,x,x^2,x^3\}$, with dimension 4. Thus $K\subset H$, which implies that $P_3\subset C[0,1]$.

Comment: Why do,you need to find a basis of $\mathcal C[0,1]$? Proving that polynomials are continuous seems to be sufficient.

Comment: Do you mean that it needs to be proved that all polynomials in $P_3$ are continuous on $[0,1]$? Why then is it asked to expose the basis of $P_3$ and its dimension?

Comment: And even if you could find a basis for $C([0,1])$ (good luck with that !), why should it contain ANY polynomial function, let alone the canonical basis of the polynomial functions ??? Saying that a space is a subspace of another doesn't imply that a basis of the first one is a subset of a basis of the last...

Comment: Those are two different questions. First one is two prove that $P_3$ is a subspace of $\mathcal C[0,1]$. For this you don't need to  find a basis of $P_3$ nor of $\mathcal C[0,1]$. Second one is to find a basis and the dimension of $P_3$ and for this you can ignore $\mathcal C[0,1]$. Finding a basis of $\mathcal C [0,1]$ is a difficult question!

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net, the question says this: "show that $P_3$ is a subspace of $C[0,1]$ by explicitly exhibiting its basis and dimension". I think this question can't be interpreted any other way than how I did interpret it. That's why I tried to solve it in a way I did above.

To show that $P_3$ is a subspace of $C[0,1]$, I think one needs to show closure under addition and scalar multiplication, as well as that the zero-function of $C[0,1]$ is in $P_3$. I.e. one needs to show that $f_1+f_2\in C[0,1]$ and $kf_1\in C[0,1]$, for $f_1, f_2\in P_3$. Do you think this is correct?

Comment: @NicolasFRANCOIS, I'm not explicitly finding a basis for $C[0,1]$, I'm just saying that since all polynomials are continuous on $\mathbb{R}$, they must be continuous on $[0,1]\subset \mathbb{R}$. And because of that, a basis for an infinite-degree polynomial must be a subset of the basis of $C[0,1]$. Why do you think is this an incorrect argument?
$$$$
"Saying that a space is a subspace of another doesn't imply that a basis of the first one is a subset of a basis of the last..." This is interesting. Can you please give a counterexample?

Comment: $(1,0),(0,1)$ is a basis of $\mathbb R^2$. ${\rm Vect}((1,1))$ is a subspace of $\mathbb R^2$. Does this space have a basis that is a subset of the basis I provided for $\mathbb R^2$ ?

Comment: The vector $(1,1)$ is not a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$.